# How to hide a program from startup list in windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, boot

i have a file .bat to run a program on windows startup. But i dont want the program icon appear in startup list. Is there any command, tips or tool that can fix my problem, i dont want people who use my computer to see my auto-startup bat file. Thanks in advance.

Comment: May you elaborate on what "startup list" you are referring to?

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Go to ‘**Start**’, and open ‘**Settings**’.
Step 2: Now select ‘**Personalizatio**n’. Then from the left menu choose ‘**Start**’.
Step 3: Find the setting that says “**Show app list in Start menu**” and turn it off to hide the app list from the Start menu.
*That is it – it is so simple to get this done!*

Comment: Thank you but please read my question, the thing i need is hide a program icon from startup list, not start menu @@